# Is there a way to add correct type annotations for this TypeScript code with an inline function class?

Tags: typescript

What type annotations can I add to inform TypeScript that this code is correct?

Yes I do need that inline function class. This code has been reduced from my actual problem to this simplified version.

```
let x = 10;
const obj = new (function() {
  if(--x) return this.constructor();
  return {};
});
```

```
'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7009)
```

I tried totally annotating everything and that doesn't fix it. Here is what that looks like:

```
type myType = { constructor(): myType };
let x: number = 10;
const obj: myType = new (function(): myType {
  if(--x) return (this as myType).constructor();
  return {} as myType;
});
```

```
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7009)
```

Is there something in the TypeScript docs I'm missing? There don't seem to be any Constructor types that are generic and the Constructor types don't really appear to be for constructors.

Comment: You're presumably looking for [construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8dON) but the example is so bizarre that I'm not sure if this is really what you want.  Does that work for your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Very cool. This works, but I don't understand why you need "as any as myType" and cannot directly force "as myType"

Comment: Because constructor functions are not considered closely enough related to arbitrary functions to allow direct assertions (since ES2015 you cannot easily call a class constructor like a function or some functions like a constructor, so it's an added bit of warning you need to overcome).  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say that a type is "newable", or a valid target for the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), you should use a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).  A construct signature can be written either as `{ new (⋯): ⋯}` like a call signature or as `new (⋯) => ⋯` like an arrow function expression.

Here's one way to write your code so it compiles:

```
let x = 10;
type MyType = { new(): {} };
const obj = new ((function (this: {}) {
  console.log(x);
  if (--x) return this.constructor();
  return {};
}) as any as MyType);
```

Here we've defined `MyType` as `{ new(): {} }`, a construct signature that takes no constructor arguments and produces a value of type `{}`.

Then we've [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the anonymous function expression is of type `MyType` via `(⋯) as any as MyType`.  Note that `(⋯) as MyType` fails because TypeScript doesn't see callable types and newable types as related enough to allow direct assertions between them. (In modern JavaScript, most class constructors will complain if you try to call them without `new`, and arrow functions complain if you try to `new` them instead of calling them, so TypeScript separates these on purpose.)  You need something intermediate that is seen as related to both; I chose [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) but you could something else, like [`Function`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function) for example.

Also I gave the anonymous function a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) of type `{}`, so that the compiler would be happy manipulating `this` inside the function body.

Anyway, now there is no error, and the value of `obj` is inferred as being of type `{}`.  Obviously in your actual use case you'll need to figure out the typings that meet your needs, but presumably whatever those are they will involve at least one construct signature.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHhC8EEYAMBuAUGAngBxBAspgCo57wDeEAdiAO4AUAlAFwTkC+E76AxgPZUAzpD4AjAFZxqdCPXoAzAK5UeYAJYDZYABZrBrDozZoIEfkL6gAdMD4BzelEbpTa+bIC0HpxABO4RV8qCB09K3NhX0VVPl8mFz8AoLZuNHYjAENBCAAxZVUNYKyCYlJnNDQgA)

Answer (score 0):

Make a generic to map it from `(...a: A) => B` type to `new (...a: A) => B`

```
function fakeNewable<F extends (...a: any) => any>(
  fn: F,
): (new (...a: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F>) /* ` & F` if you also need other props */ {
  return fn as any
} 
function foo() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'foo' : { foo: 'bar' };
}
let v = new (fakeNewable(foo))
//  ^?
// let v: string | { foo: string; }
```

(remember, that if you return `undefined` inside `new` call, you'll get the constructed object)

Comment: unfortunately I do need the type to be an inline function. If I didn't I could just use a class like a a normal